# React-admin does not run after migration from admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, migration, react-admin

After migrating from admin-on-rest to react-admin and running npm start, the create-react-app does not throw any errors, but the console is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined

having the following stacktrace:

[error stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMNbO.png)

Environment:
Windows 10, Chrome

Dependencies:

```
   "material-ui": "^0.20.1",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-admin": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include error messages as formatted text, not as image. This makes it possible to search for the error.

Answer (score 1):

React-admin uses material ui **v1**. You're using an old version of material-ui.

PS: Just in case you don't already know, we have an [upgrade guide](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) which might help